# Maintaining div size based on an image loaded externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the div structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="mainG mainGT">
        <div class="rawV">
            <div class="svs"></div>
            <div class="drgM"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm loading an external image into `drgM`. Now I need div `svs` to be same size as `drgM` (height and width). So I wrapped both `drgM` and `svs` inside rawV. My question is, how do I make the `svs` to be the same size as `drgM` at all times? So basically if `mainGT` height is changed, `drgM` and `svs` should scale proportionately maintaining their aspect ratio?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/5ppbgxvq/1/) including the css

Comment: Do you want `div.svs` to overlap `div.drgM`, as in, stacked one over the other like an overlay?

Comment: @MarcAudet. thanks. Yes, I want them to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be close to what you need.  If you change the width of `.mainG` the image and overlay (`.svs`) will scale accordingly.

It might be possible to scale by changing the height, let me know if that is critical.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
.mainG {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 400px;
}
.rawV {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.drgM img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.svs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="mainG mainGT">
        <div class="rawV">
            <div class="svs"></div>
            <div class="drgM"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just one more thing, If I load an inline svg into `drgM ` will that work same as an img?

Comment: If your SVG has intrinsic dimensions, then it should behave like an image.  I can't guarantee it, but please try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit and added another wrapper for .svs and .drgM since I'm not sure how you want .rawV to work.

```
<div class="rawV">
        <div class="resize">
            <div class="svs"></div>
        <div class ="drgM"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ppbgxvq/2/

Basically, `.resize` will resize depending on `.drgM` and `.svs` will fill the size of `.rawV` giving it the same size as `.drgM`

Comment: thanks.  But `drgM` and `svs` does not change their sizes when I changed the height of `mainGT`.

Comment: try this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/5ppbgxvq/3/

I removed the extra element and used the `rawV` back again and just used percentage so that `.drgM` resizes when `mainGT` resizes.

Comment: thanks.. that works too. I find Marc Audet's answer more accurate. +10

Answer (score 0):

Set the css `height` for both `drgM` and `svs` as `auto`.
Setting the `height` as a **percentage** means it is relative to its parent element.

Comment: thanks. but what about the width? how would `svs` set it's width to the same size as `drgM`?